# In Access 2007 is there a way to just delete an adhoc query instead of saving it?

Tags: microsoft-access

Say you have a tab open that reads "Query10", is there way to close it and forget about it instead of saving it as Query10 searching for "Query10" again in "All Access Objects" and then deleting it from there?

Comment: It's just kind of annoying...

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding the question; if you haven't saved it, just close it and choose not to save it? If you saved it, then you are annoying yourself.

Comment: I didn't save it.  There's a dialog box that comes up with two buttons when I try to close my query "OK" and "Cancel"  When you click OK it saves the query, when you click "Cancel" it throws you back into editing it.  I'm looking for a dialog that says "would you like to save the query?" with three buttons "Yes" "No" and "Cancel"  what happened to that?

Comment: I have 2010, which offers the 3 choices when closing the query. Previous version was 2003 which also offered the same. One would assume 2007 would do the same.

Comment: It's odd; sometimes it does, but the majority of the time it doesn't.